# how to use last part of a class name to target with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I have a common class name which repeats itself in different pages. As you can see the class name follows this convention:

article-**number**-slide-**number**

These links open a certain slide information. This number is different for each slide, therefore I would like to know if its possible to target

```
$('.hotspot').click(function() {
        $('...SLIDE-2').animate({right: "0"}, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Is it possible to target the end of the class name of an element?

```
<div class="hotspots-image">

    <img class="image"
         src="IMG-SRC"
         alt=""
        />

    <h1 class="home-banner">
        <em>lala collection</em><br>
        white &amp; fluffy
    </h1>

    <a class="hotspot article-1-slide-2" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon pp-icon icon-hotspot">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 1</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hotspot article-2-slide-2" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon pp-icon icon-hotspot">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 2</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hotspot article-3-slide-2" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon pp-icon icon-hotspot">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 3</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hotspot article-4-slide-2" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon pp-icon icon-hotspot">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 4</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hotspot article-5-slide-2" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon pp-icon icon-hotspot">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 5</span>
    </a>
    <a class="hotspot article-6-slide-2" href="#">
        <span class="hotspot-icon pp-icon icon-hotspot">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 6</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @cVplZ hi, the issue that the answers provided do not answer my question. Your answer is a work around and it works but I'm asking exclusively to select a class by selecting only parts of the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work for you, I dont know is it correct method

```
   $('.hotspot').click(function() {
        $("a[name$='slide-2']").animate({right: "0"}, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hotspot').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({right: "0"}, 500);
        return false;
});
```

just use `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).animate({right: "0"}, 500);
```

instead of

```
 $('...SLIDE-2').animate({right: "0"}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the element you want to animate is also the element you want to click, you just need to use `$(this)` here:

```
$(this).animate({right: 0}, 500);
```

Btw, you don't need `"` around `0`. Save 2 bytes :P